# Export Report from NetSuite with Java

Tags: java, netsuite

I'd like to export a "Report" from NetSuite (example URL: https://{{accountId}}.app.netsuite.com/app/reporting/reportrunner.nl?cr=127).

I've been able to use the SuiteTalk Sample Applications (Java) (http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-sample-applications.shtml) to export a Saved Search, but I cannot find anything in the API that can export a Report.

Here's the example code for exporting a Saved Search. I cannot find any classes that suggest they can export a Report:

```
TransactionSearchAdvanced advSearch = new 
TransactionSearchAdvanced();

advSearch.setSavedSearchId(searchId);

SearchResult searchResult = client.callSearch(advSearch); final 
String jobId = client.getLastJobId();
```

Answer (score 1):

Supported Record Types for SuiteTalk are listed in the Schema Browser: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2019_1/schema/record/salesorder.html

Reports are not among them, so unfortunately you are out of luck. You will likely have to build a Saved Search that mimics the values, or that gets you as much data as possible so your client side can mimic the report data. Not ideal, of course, but probably your best bet if you're stuck with SuiteTalk.